# Loading data from associated model in same query in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, thinking-sphinx, eager-loading

Basically, I have a Listing model, where each listing has a country id. I need the country name in my search results view. I know I can do `@listing.country.name`, but this performs an extra query for each listing in my search results. I'm using Thinking Sphinx, and in my controller I have

```
@listings = Listing.search(@ts_params).page(page_num).per(limit)
```

I have tried adding `.includes(:countries)` and variations thereof but no luck.

What's the best way to go about this? I want the country data to be fetched in the same query as the listings.

I have exactly the same issue with listing images - it is performing an extra query for every listing to find the image, when surely it can be done in one with joins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to eager load the associated model (to avoid an N + 1 query problem), or are you trying to load the associated model into fields on the parent model?

If it's the former, you're probably better off forgetting about `:select` and instead of `:joins` using:

```
ts_params[:sql][:include] = :countries, :listing_images
```

Now you should be able to call `listing.countries` and `listing.listing_images` to access child models, as normal.

Comment: Thanks taavo, at the moment I have the select/joins working, as I figured less queries is better? The :include option would work too but it loads a lot of unnecessary data, as I only need one 'listing_image' result for each listing. Perhaps I could create a new association for the listing - has_one :main_image which just pulls one image?

Comment: Yeah, if you only need one, and you want to be able to load it using activerecord's `includes` (here triggered via `:include`), then you're going to need a `has_one`.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking Sphinx provides functionality to eager load associated entities, so for eager loading we don't need to add `[:sql]`. Following is the way to do this.
For eager loading associated entities using sphinx.

```
ts_params[:include] = [:country, :listing_image]
```

Comment: This approach is for TS v1/v2, the `:sql` nesting is required for TS v3.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this using the :sql hash provided by Thinking Sphinx. I now have the following:

```
@ts_params[:sql][:joins] = "INNER JOIN countries ON countries.id = listings.country_id INNER JOIN listing_images ON listing_images.listing_id = listings.id"
@ts_params[:sql][:select] = "listings.*, countries.name as country_name, listing_images.image as image_name"
```

This is correctly retrieving the country name and image name, but I still have a bit of work to do in making it work with the images - I think that will deserve its own question!

Answer (score 0):

Current v4 syntax is:

```
Article.search :sql => {:include => :user}
```

Ref: https://freelancing-gods.com/thinking-sphinx/v4/searching.html